# Show output in two columns Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 execution commands and we need to have it as a otput file (csv). The results should be shown in two columns next to each other. I am not sure how to use "format-table" or hashtables?
It gets attributes from Vmware

```
get-vm | get-annotation -customattribute "GrupaAktualizacji" | select value
get-vm | select name, @{N="DnsName"; E={$_.ExtensionData.Guest.Hostname}}
```

Below the example output

```
Name             DnsName                                  
----             -------                                  
examplename    example.com
```

and

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32> get-vm | get-annotation -customattribute "GrupaAktualizacji" | select value

Value
-----
GWT  
     
GW3  
GW2  
GW3  
GW3  
GW2
```

Comment: `Get-Vm | select Name, @{N="DnsName"; E={$_.ExtensionData.Guest.Hostname}}, @{N="GrupaAktualizacji";E={$_ |Get-Annotation -CustomAttribute "GrupaAktualizacji" |ForEach Value}}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you....

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, if you post your suggestion as an answer instead as a comment, then it would be possible to mark it as a correct answer :)